# Laravel join two tables in different databases

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have already defined my connections in `database.php` :

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'db1'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            ...
        ],

        'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'db2'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
         ...
        ],
```

I want to join table user from `db2` with table ticket from `db1`.Please help is appreciated.I tried the one below but since ticket table is from db1 is not recognized

```
$user= DB::connection("mysql2")->table('User')
        ->join('ticket', 'User.Id', '=','ticket.user_id')
        ->select('User.*')
        ->where('ticket.id', '=', 1)
        ->get();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far i know you can't do this, but if the databases are on the same server you cant create a View on the database you actually connect or you need to do is FEDERATED Storage Engine, hope it helps

Comment: @UlyssesMarx the db are on the same server

Comment: @UlyssesMarx - Mysql does allow you to query two Databases at the same time, it's one of the only DB engines that does.  One should note though, that the DB user must have privilege to both databases, this is likly the issue you face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer that I wanted was:

```
$user=DB::table(DB::raw('sarida_test.user AS db1_tb1'))
            ->join(DB::raw('task_flow.tickets AS db2_tb2'),'db1_tb1.Id','=','db2_tb2.user_id')
```

Answer (score 2):

MySql allows you to access and even join from two database on the same host using the same connection and user. I actually have a cron job that does this every night. We have 2 copies of the same data, one is live for out clients one is for management to edit, at night the two are compared and changes are pushed to the live copy.  This way our clients are protected if someone makes a mistake in the updates as it's not immediately live.  These are 2 separate database that with the magic of a full outer join are synced up.  (this is something that fits our specific needs and I wouldn't recommend it for everyone)

This is important because the user must have access to both databases, This should be obvious but it is often overlooked as one just assumes it's the case, but often times its not.  Furthermore Mysql's error reporting on no access is really poor and it often takes the form of no "Seeing" the other database and just acts like its not their (this may or may not be the correct behaviour depending who you ask and in what context)

Likely your problem is one of privilege to the second database.

Comment: I have found out the sql query I need to access the two methods,the prbi is when I create a `$data=DB::raw("...");` and then `return view('view') ->with('user',$user); ` it doesnt return nothing

Comment: I suggest checking if the user you are using has access to the other database.  For example query only that database with that user and see if they can access it.

Comment: it would be much easier if you could add the way you do it.It would help me a lot.simply add your example I have already created a mysql2 conn but dont know how to use it in my actual select query

Comment: You don't use it, you use one connection with the same user that has access to both databases.  That is if you want to do a join on the tables.  Then you just add `database.table` instead of `table` it's that simple.  But the user has to be able to access both tables.   In Laravel  I am not sure how you do it, but its trivial with raw sql

Comment: You can't do it on Laravel, the easy way is you need to connect by shell or your admin an run the sql script that i wrotte you:
`CREATE VIEW `db1`.`ticket` AS SELECT * FROM `db2`.`ticket`;`

Answer (score 0):

So if they are on the same same server just make a view like :

```
CREATE VIEW `D2`.`example` AS SELECT * FROM `D1`.`T1`;
```

Comment: I am using laravel how do I add this to my code,this is only a sql function

Comment: Man how can you ask this if you are asking for MySQL info, this is no problem of laravel, you need to connect to mysql by shell or your admin and modify the CREATE VIEW for your own settings.

Comment: where do I ask for mysql info?